# Regex for matching a route template with a request path

Tags: c#, regex

I need to build a regex in `C#` for matching these examples of url pairs below.

```
// Ex 01
// Route Template :      "/path/{id}/path2"
// Actual Request Path : "/path/1512312/path2"
// expected result = [match]

// Ex 02
// Route Template :      "/{name}/path/path2"
// Actual Request Path : "/damon/path/path2"
// expected result = [match]

// Ex 03
// Route Template :      "/path/{name}/{id}/path2"
// Actual Request Path : "/path/damon/1512312/path2"
// expected result = [match]

// Ex 04
// Route Template :      "/path/{name}/{id}/path2"
// Actual Request Path : "/path/damon/path2"
// expected result = [doesn't match!!!]
```

I tried with this regex, but it doesn't work on multiple occurrences like **Ex 03** above.

```
var regex = new Regex("\\{.*?\\}");
string replacedRouteTemplate = regex.Replace("/path/{name}/{id}/path2", ".");

// this result below becomes false... when matching the Ex 03 example.
bool result = Regex.IsMatch(replacedRouteTemplate , "/path/damon/1512312/path2"); 

// Single occurrence works fine. the IsMatch returns "true" this time.
replacedRouteTemplate = regex.Replace("/path/{id}/path2", ".");
result = Regex.IsMatch(replacedRouteTemplate, "/path/1512312/path2");
```

**It's a simple question.**

I want my regex to be able to match multiple occurrences. Which patterns do I have to add there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please double-check your code, especially the way [Regex.IsMatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_IsMatch_System_String_System_String_) is invoked - an input string should go on the first place, whereas a pattern is the second argument.

In order to match all chars, the replacement string should be revised from `.` to at least `.+`. I'd actually suggest narrowing it down to `[^/]+` (see [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JCKPlr)):

```
var regex = new Regex("\\{.*?\\}");
string replacedRouteTemplate = regex.Replace("/path/{name}/{id}/path2", "[^/]+");

bool result = Regex.IsMatch("/path/damon/1512312/path2", replacedRouteTemplate);
Console.WriteLine($"Result 1: {result}");

replacedRouteTemplate = regex.Replace("/path/{id}/path2", "[^/]+");
result = Regex.IsMatch("/path/1512312/path2", replacedRouteTemplate);
Console.WriteLine($"Result 2: {result}");
```

The code above outputs:

```
Result 1: True
Result 2: True
```